# Redirect to different default pages/controllers for every role type - MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, roles

Hi I am developping an application in MVC5

After login, logged in user automaticaly redirected to HomeController's index page.

I have 3 different rôles :
1 Operator
2 Administrator
3 TicketManager

When a operator log in, he should be automatically redirected to the OperatorCOntroller 's index page.

I am trying to find a solution for long time but not able te get a solution which can work.
I tried in HomeController's Index page

```
if(User.isinrole("Operator")){return RedirectionOnAction("index","Operator")}
```

it works but is not ideal solution.

Comment: Are there any other roles? Is there a controller with the same name for each role? Can a user have multiple roles?

Comment: Why is it not Ideal.  It's easy to understand, easy to maintain and extensible.  Somewhere some how they have to be *mapped*.  What happens if someone is in both Administrator and Operator?

Comment: no there are only three. Yes controller's name is same as role name in database.

Comment: @Erik Philips, it is not Idea because, the title contains a url which redirect website to home page. As a user is logged in, it will never redirect that user to home page of website.

Comment: @HarjinderRandhawa Sorry I don't understand that sentence.  The other issue is that the user roles won't be populated until a redirect, so at a bare minimum you'll probably need two redirects and since it's only during login it should be acceptable.

Comment: @Erik Philips Actualy the logo of website contains adress (url /home/index) of index page which is as default index in homecontroller. As a user with role of "operator" is connected and if he click on the logo of website, instead of consulting the home page of website he will b redirected to his home page. 

I hope it is clear now

Comment: Sure makes sense, so why not make the actionlink for the image dynamic, seems pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing I can come up with:

```
string userRole = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
if (userRole != null) return RedirectToAction("Index", userRole);
```